# How to disable special characters from appearing when keyboard shortcuts are pressed?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I am using the Python IDLE and I can use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> shortcut to comment out a line of code. But that same shortcut also prints the '♦' character. So when I use the shortcut it does comment that line of code but at the same time prints the ♦ character. A similar case holds for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>. So how can I disable this special character from appearing when I use keyboard shortcuts?

By the way, I am using Windows 10

Comment: Please see Alex Quinn's answer on this page from "Removing control characters from a string in python" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324790/removing-control-characters-from-a-string-in-python   Nine years old but should still work.

Comment: @vssher I don't see how that will help, that post is about programming while my question is about keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: All I did was select the line I want to remove and press the Backspace key. No other charactures, line removed. Peace

Comment: @vssher I don't want to remove the line, I want to comment it out